# Flutter plugin not installed when using Android-Studio

Tags: android-studio, flutter

Hi I am getting the following error.

```
$ flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 1.20.2, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18362.1016], locale en-IN)

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.3)
[!] Android Studio
    X Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
    X Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
[√] VS Code (version 1.48.2)
[√] Connected device (1 available)

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

I have installed both plugins and everything in environment variable.

I installed Android studio in **my custom path, this may be the issue**. I have given the current `android-studio` path using `flutter config` command.

When I check the Installation path the plugin is not there(flutter and dart). It is installed in `C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\Google\AndroidStudio4.1\` path.
So I set that path then shows another error that is, `embedded java is not found`.

Also I tried copying it to custom path. But no luck.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing everything on vs code having flutter and dart not installed on android studio should not be an issue. You only need android studio to connect to the emulator. I can run my flutter code with both plugins not installed.

Comment: I am checking with command line only. Firstly it shows Android is not installed, when Android Studio installed it shows plugin is installed.

Comment: Ah, but if the plugins are now installed what is the issue